# Preferred Currency API returning only ID

Tags: facebook-graph-api, currency

I'm currently trying to implement the preferred currency API, but all the graph API is returning to me is the user ID.

I go to the following link:

https://graph.facebook.com/100001342672661?fields=currency&access_token=XXXX

I get this back:

{
   "id": "100001342672661"
}

I've looked in the graph API explorer and get the same result. There are no errors, and "currency" appears to be a valid field, it's just not returning anything. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The FacebookId and the user access_token are not matching, this is why you're getting only the FacebookId as an answer.

1. Allow the app on your developer account
2. Get a user token for your app: https://developers.facebook.com/tools/access_token/
3. Go to https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=currency&access_token=XXX (XXX being the user token you just retrieved)

Comment: Turns out this was the problem (sorry it took me so long to respond, but I had forgotten I asked this question). I was using an app access token rather then a user access token when calling the graph API, so of course it wasn't going to work. The fact that there were no errors threw me off-previous experience with the graph API before this point had been that an "invalid token" error was thrown in cases like this.

Answer (score 0):

Currency is indeed a valid field. Are you sure it is set? For me it seems it isn't (and that's why it only returns you the id) but I'll look to find out it if there's any bug related to it.

Comment: How can I tell if it's not set? Right now it says "Currencies will be shown and purchased as US Dollar." in the payments tab. I've changed that to other currencies but have not seen any change in the data that is returned.